# Convert Vidoza API to python class

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am new with python. I have this API code and want to make a python class.
This is the code I have so far and want to convert it to python code:

`curl -X GET \
  https://api.vidoza.net/v1/upload/http/server \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer fB5T3IaHjtUXQNb3IH0Lm4epcRHnkAK' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'`

`curl -X POST \
  https://upload22.vidoza.net/upload/03 \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F is_xhr=true \
  -F sess_id=SDErfNTBc03PYnmw \
  -F file=@/tmp/video.mp4`

Comment: [`requests documentation`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) probably the best place to get started.